# f# function for checking if a string is palidrome without using built in methods

Tags: string, f#

f# beginner trying to check for if a string is palidrome in f# without  reverse or built in methods. Here is what I came up with so far I feel I'm close just a little off. This is not currently compiling.

```
       let ispalidrome (str:string) =
            let strlength = str.Length 
            let result = for i in 0 .. < strlength / 2 do
                if str.[0] <> strlength then false
                else true

             result
        //unit test
        ispalidrome "noon"
```

Answer (score 4):

The main problem with your code is that, in F#, you cannot break from a `for` loop. This means that you need to write the iteration using recursion, rather than using a `for` loop (F# has some support for imperative programming, but not for imperative `break`, `continue` and `return`).

The easiest way to do this is to write an inner `loop` function that takes the index we are currently looking at. If this is after the half of the word, we return `true`. Otherwise, we compare `str.[i]` with `str.[str.Length-1-i]` and call the function recursively:

```
let ispalidrome (str:string) =
  let rec loop i =
    if i > str.Length / 2 then true
    else str.[i] = str.[str.Length-1-i] && loop (i + 1)
  loop 0
```